# Unity 5.3, error in XCODE (Simulator)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator

When I try to run the project in Xcode it gives me the following error

[image]

It happens only in Unity 5.3, in Unity 5.2 all is ok.

Is anyone knows how do I fix it?

Comment: make sure your build settings in xCode look like this:
[Settings](http://i63.tinypic.com/28a3i1c.png)

Comment: I have just changed settings for these http://puu.sh/lV4pD/0672e291bc.png but it still gives me the same error